# fix URL problems with includes for any page in any location

Tags: php

i've had a good solution for this but in any case, im thinking security will concern me.

i have a folder on my root folder `'core/includes/include_file.file'` i include this file to any of my other root files like index.php using include function

what if i want to include this file from a file three folders deep `'products/p1/p2/HERE'`
i get an error so i fixed with going back a directory `'../../../'` now it included but everything like images on the include file still dont show up thats because the urls on those sources are still set to source from the root
how can i create a global variable that contains the full url of my website to each src so i just do something like this
`<img src="<?php $url.'images/icon.png?>">` to work from any page location?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php echo "http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>
```

it will give base url. after this you can add the folder structure.

Answer (score 0):

you can make a $URL varible before the include function, and put $URl before any url in the included page .

like :

```
$URL = "../home";
include "home/file1.php"
```

and in any url in the file1.php :

```
<img src="<?php echo $URL ?>/image.jpg"/>
```